# Setting Boost in Solr - Adding conditions

Tags: php, apache, search, solr, search-engine

I would like to know if there is a way / method to set conditional boosts

Ex: 
if( category:1 )( field_1^1.5 field_2^1.2 )else if( category:3 )(  field_3^7.5 field_4^5.2 )

I'm planning to set the "qf" and "pf" parameters this way in order to boost my results, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually - yes, it could be done using function queries (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery), it contains if function, but I wasn't able to do that by myself, since i couldn't use `==` operator.

Also, you could write your own function query.

But anyway right now it more looks like a good place to start, not concrete answer.

Comment: If possible can you explain it a bit more? with an example

Comment: example of function query?

Comment: Yea if possible, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two ways of doing this...

1. First way, is by simplifying things at index time, so maybe create other set of redundant fields in the schema (ex: boostfield_1, boostfield_2, etc), and if the document category is 1, you can set the value of boostfield_1 to field_1, and boostfield_2 to field_2. But if category is 2, you can set it to other fields.

This will allow you to use "pf" straight away without having any conditions, as you already specified the conditions at index time, and indexed the document differently based on the category. The problem with that, is you won't be able to change the score of boost values of the fields according to the category, but it is a simpler way anyway

1. Use the _val_, or bq parameters to specify a boost query, and you can write the same query differently, so you can write the same condition as the following:

   url?q=query AND _val_:"(category:1 AND (field_1:query OR field_2:query)) OR (category:3 AND field_2:query)"

The little problem here as well is you repeat the query text in every inner query, which is not a big deal anyway.

Comment: The second method using "_val_" isn't that equal to "fl" ( filtering )? it looks pretty much like it. I couldn't understand the first method could you please explain it a bit further?

Comment: using \_val_ does not affect the query results, it just affects the boosting and scores. If you add or remove \_val_ it won't have any effect on the number of results

Comment: The first method mentioned lets say there was a field holding vehicle brands like "Toyota", "Mitsubishi", "Suzuki", "Ford" etc.. so what you are saying is when indexing index the field values in several fields like field_1 , field_2, field_3 and then use "pf" or "qf" for boosting am I right?

So what you are saying is to give the query under the "bq" parameter
like
`bq="(category:1 AND (field_1:query OR field_2:query)) OR (category:3 AND field_2:query)"`

Comment: yes, I think so, bq should affect score only, but not matching. So, you can leave the q field as it is, and bq will just affect scoring